# python import from different directory-'attempted relative import beyond top-level package'

Tags: python

```
proj1
  |__ py1.py
  |__ py2.py
pkg
  |__ __init__.py
  |__ comm_f1.py
  |__mod1
  |  |__ __init__.py
  |  |__ f1.py
  |  |__ f2.py
  |__mod2
  |  |__ __init__.py
  |  |__ f3.py
  |  |__ f4.py
```

I knew there are some similar questions, but mine seems a little different.
I have the project and package directories as above. The 'pkg' directory contains some basic functions and classes I will use for my project 'proj1' or 'proj2', etc., so that I don't want to keep 'pkg' under 'proj1'. I debugged 'proj1' with VS2015,  told it to refer to 'pkg' directory and it works quite well. But now I create comm_f1.py which has some common functions/classes I believe could be used by different sub modules such as 'mod1' and 'mod2', etc. for example, in f3.py I want to import my class from comm_f1 by using:

```
from ..comm_f1 import myclass
```

It give me an error message 'attempted relative import beyond top-level package'
how can I solve this problem elegantly? And I don't want to involve the name of 'pkg' (or absolute directory path name with 'pkg') since I probably will change the name of 'pkg' and I suppose since comm_f1.py is only at f3.py's parent directory, it does not necessary need to touch its grand-parent 'pkg'

Answer (score 2):

You can try to expand your path and then import like this

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
from comm_f1 import myclass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
proj1
  |__ py1.py
  |__ py2.py
pkg
  |__ __init__.py
  |__common
  |  |__ __init__.py
  |  |__ comm_f1.py
  |__mod1
  |  |__ __init__.py
  |  |__ f1.py
  |  |__ f2.py
  |__mod2
  |  |__ __init__.py
  |  |__ f3.py
  |  |__ f4.py
```

I didn't find an exact solution, but if I put this `comm_f1.py` into an directory `common`, claim `from comm_f1 import *` in the correspondent `__init__.py` and then I can use everything by using `from common import myclass` from anywhere. So I added an module. I don't know if it is a good solution or it will have any potential problem, but seems working.